# Adding a Google Map with a Marker in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a simple google map with a marker in wordpress but it doesn't work. To do that i used the "entire code" of this tutorial  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map#maps_add_map-html. I did the first steps and i have a key.

Are there somethings in the code that I should modify or integrate?

Thank's

Comment: It's much easier for people to help you if you post your current code (what you've tried so far) and what problem you are running into.

Comment: You should include what is in your mymap.js file too. It would also be better if you added this to your question instead of the comments. You can edit the post and embed code.

Comment: Hello, the code is the same as the one in the tutorial. I just changed the path of my .css and .js files and I added the .html code in my website page using "Custom HTML". Is that the right way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Embed a google maps with marker using iframe]

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d387190.27986637485!2d-74.25986055279087!3d40.69767007193516!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNew%20York%2C%20NY%2C%20USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2seg!4v1664812937761!5m2!1sen!2seg" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

Steps

1. Go to google maps  make sure your logged in
2. Search for the location you want to add
3. Select Share
4. Select embed a map
5. Copy the html  tag provided by google. this is what i did before for a clients project. in wordpress.

References
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map